# Correct use of the present participle of verb "to pacifiy"?

Tags: phrases, expression-choice, present-participles, nonfinite-verbs, is-it-a-verb

I wonder if this expression can be correctly formulated and completed 
using the present participle *pacifying* of the verb *to pacifiy*
as an adjective at least, instead of *pacifist*.

- He/she is a pacifying person.

This is what *pacifying* tends to do:

> tending to calm the emotions and relieve stress.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66310/discussion-on-question-by-m-nemo-correct-use-of-the-present-participle-of-verb-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use it like that.

Some examples:

> He is a pacifying man.
>   => *He is a man **who pacifies**.*

This is similar to:

> He has a calming voice.
>   => *He has a voice **which calms others**.*
>
> He is an interesting person.
>   => *He is a person **who interests me/people**.*

---

However, there are other words that are equally correct, but have a different meaning. For example:

> He is a pacified man.
>   => *He is a man **who has been pacified** (by someone else).*
>
> He has a calm voice.
>   => *He has a voice **which is calm**.*
>
> He is an interested person.
>   => *He is a person **who is interested in me/people**.*

---

In short, "a pacifying person" is correct, as long as you're talking about a person who **pacifies others**, and not a person who is **pacified by someone else**.

Answer (score -1):

***Pacifist*** is a noun as well as adjective.

***Pacifying*** is a gerund adjective, but it cannot be used as a noun. That would be ***pacifier***.

But on the wider question, I would agree that the term *pacifist* has acquired too specialised a connotation to be used generally - and it almost never is.

A *pacifist* is a person who takes a political stand against the use of military power.

A *pacifier* is someone who acts in the interests of conflict prevention and/or its mitigation.  (A *pacifier* is also the name that Americans give to a baby's dummy)

Comment: So, my expression is false. I thought it was possible because it is possible to formulate it in French.

Comment: "Pacifying" can be used as a noun, and it does not mean the same as "pacifier". It's hardly ever used as a noun (just not that common), but that doesn't meant it _can't_ be used as one.

Comment: @Flater If you can provide me with a suitable example I undertake to edit my answer.

Comment: "Pacifying people is the best way to ensure their loyalty", "I am tired of your constant pacifying", "Pacifying has never helped anyone get promoted in the army". Pacifier does not fit in any of these examples, since pacifier refers to an **object** (or person) that pacifies, as opposed to referring to the **act** of pacification.

Comment: Your first two examples seem to me to be present participle verbs. The third example I believe is a gerund (and hence a noun) - but have you honestly ever heard anyone use *pacifying* in quite that way? Wouldn't it be more usual to use "pacification"?